Reorder bar plot in ggplot R, by Frequency AND Alphabetically
Bar plot in ggplot are automatically arranged alphabetically. My plots are actually plotted alphabetically inverted and I can invert the alphabetical order and make it forward.
If i put the condition to order the plot by frequency, classes with the same frequency appear in the plot in the counter-alphabetical order.
This is what the plot does:
G - 60
T - 50
C - 40
B - 40
A - 40

This is what i need from the plot:
G - 60
T - 50
A - 40
B - 40
C - 40

This i the code I've written to order the plot by frequency and i cannot figure out an alternative that works. I see that it's possible to add a function to "reorder" but i don't know how to use it here.
ggplot(data) +
 aes(x = reorder(Names, Frequency), y = Frequency)

EDIT
Data:
fam_sub <- structure(
  list(
    Abs_fam.Var1 = c(
      "Apio",
      "Myria",
      "Xyla",
      "Rhyti",
      "Hypo",
      "Phaci"
    ),
    Abs_fam.Freq = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 53L)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-6L),
  groups = structure(
    list(
      Abs_fam.Freq = c(1L, 2L, 8L, 53L),
      .rows = structure(
        list(1:3, 4L, 5L, 6L),
        ptype = integer(0),
        class = c("vctrs_list_of",
                  "vctrs_vctr", "list")
      )
    ),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA,-4L),
    .drop = TRUE
  ),
  class = c("grouped_df",
            "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Plot code:
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(fam_sub, aes(x = reorder(Abs_fam.Var1, Abs_fam.Freq), y = Abs_fam.Freq)) +
  geom_col(fill = "#559355") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal()


Please dput() your data.

Hi rousou, depending on how many unique values you have in column Names, you could convert the column to class Factor and relevel by for example using the fct_relevel function

@Edward i added the data and plot code. Thank you for your help.

@baobab can you provide an example with the code? I'm not really into coding I'm just starting and I understand better from examples.

I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do it but this is may be an option. What i did was assign levels based on first value of the column "Abs_fam.Freq" followed by alphabetical order of "Abs_fam.Var1".
library(tidyverse)
    
lvs <- arrange(fam_sub, Abs_fam.Freq, desc(Abs_fam.Var1))$Abs_fam.Var1
    
fam_sub_2 <- fam_sub %>%
      mutate(Abs_fam.Var1 = factor(Abs_fam.Var1, levels = lvs))
    
ggplot(fam_sub_2, aes(x = Abs_fam.Var1, y = Abs_fam.Freq)) +
      geom_col(fill = "#559355") +
      coord_flip() +
      theme_minimal()


